# No module named 'surprise'

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed scikit-surprise from anaconda command prompt 'conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise',  but on jupyter get error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'surprise'.
[image]
I have installed.
conda version: 4.9.2 
python version: 3.8.3 
jupyter version: 1.0.0 
scikit-surprise version: 1.1.1

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check that you have activated your conda environment:

```
conda activate env
```

and then:

```
pip install scikit-surprise
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update PIP, I always find when importing random and other math functions that Pip plays weirdly and claims its not found, and I've used suprise once and the same occurred for me there, but this might not work for you, Hope this helps!